# What determines what super.prop refers to in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, super

I'm confused about why exactly super gets set the way it does inside of a class.

In static elements, super.x refers to Parent.x

In methods & field declaration assignments, super.x refers to Parent.prototype.x

MDN says super is either Parent or Parent.prototype, depending on whether the execution context is instance creation or class initialization. To me this makes sense for static elements, where super is seen during class initialization, and for field declarations, where super is seen during instance creation. However, aren't methods evaluated during class initialization, so that they can be put on the class's prototype, and not during instance creation?

Comment: Is it just as simple as: super.x is always Parent.prototype.x, except inside static elements, where it is Parent.x... And this is all so because this is just how the spec defines the behavior of super...?

Answer (score 0):

> aren't methods evaluated during class initialization

No

Methods are not cloned or evaluated, prototype chain is checked when method is not found in instance of the class

```js
class Parent {
  doSomething() {}
}

const parent = new Parent()

class Child extends Parent {}

const child = new Child()

console.log(parent.doSomething === child.doSomething)
```

Comment: so class methods aren't evaluated during class initialization, they are just placed on  Class.prototype... I think I'm misunderstanding the term "evaluated", but even still... It's not like methods are evaluated during instance creation either, right?